# Is it normal for ESRI World Locator to return half of a postal code?

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-server, geocoding, web-service, postal-code

I am using the [ESRI World Locator](https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer) to find address candidates for a location in Canada.  I should preface that I live in the United States and have a rudimentary at best understanding of international postal codes. The problem I'm seeing is that the candidate's "Match_addr" looks like this:

```
"Match_addr": "168 Garrison Rd, Fort Erie, Ontario, L2A"
```

I am expecting the postal code in these candidates to have 6 characters (7 if you include the space), but these only have three. Granted, there is a PostalExt field in the outfields that has the other three characters of the code.

Is this a bug?  If not, can I reliably interrogate the PostalExt outfield for the full code?

Comment: What is your input parameters for the address request?

Comment: /findAddressCandidates?token=[token]&f=pjson&singleLine=168+Garrison+Rd%2c+Fort+Erie%2c+ON%2c+Canada&outSR=102100&outfields=*

Comment: Have you tried http:// versus https:// at the beginning of your `findaddress` candidate search?

Comment: My best guess is the underlying data isn't licensed for the full postal code in Canada. Postal Codes are "owned" by [Canada Post(https://www.canadapost.ca/cpc/en/business/marketing/audience/license-data.page) . I don't see full PC in a few attempted [addresses:](http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?SingleLine=1600+Carling+Ave+Ottawa+Ontario&category=&outFields=*&forStorage=false&f=pjson)

Comment: Please no not delete and re-ask your questions: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/258658/115

Comment: It's is not a bug but a license issue for canadian postal codes. @KHibma is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with ESRI Support, I found out that the data that created the locator does not have 6 character postal codes for Canadian addresses.  There was an internal enhancement request made (000101787) but the issue was closed, reason being the data does not have 6 character postal codes for PointAddress and StreetAddress matches.  @KHibma 's comment is likely the reason but I don't have enough rep to +1 his comment or mark as answer.  A sincere thank you for all who replied.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that it is a bug, I haven't found any cases at this point to indicate that. However, based on your input and Esri [`findaddress`](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/geocode/api-reference/geocoding-find-address-candidates.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DC481411A8494D809D3501B79059DBA6) documentation, you should be receiving all outfields including the postal codes.

> **Multifield request URL:** In this example, the street address component (380 New York St) is passed as the value for the address parameter; the city component (Redlands) as the value for the city parameter; the state component (CA) as the region parameter; and the ZIP Code (92373) as the value for the postal parameter. ***Also in this example, all possible output fields are returned (outFields=*), even if they don't contain a value.***